# Reading from a text file and storing in a String

Tags: java, file, file-io

How can we read data from a text file and store in a String variable?

is it possible to pass the filename in a method and it would return the String  which is the text from the file.

What kind of utilities do I have to import? A list of statements will be great.

Comment: Java, simple java language.

Comment: why you dont tag it? so let people see

Comment: You will need `java.io.*`

Comment: The answer to the questions "yes".  Take a look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) for more details

Comment: Please share what you've tried.

Comment: @MrD - Correction: he's asked people to do his work for him and I asked him what code he has tried.  The answer is "_he hasn't tried anything_" (including google).  Feel free to answer this question if you want, but I wouldn't bother.  This question will just litter the site.  Your answer will just encourage the OP to continue to be lazy and abuse StackOverflow.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

These are the necersary imports:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
```

And this is a method that will allow you to read from a File by passing it the filename as a parameter like this: `readFile("yourFile.txt");`

```
String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use Apache's FileUtils library to do this in one line... There are **SO** many questions about this it's not even funny.

Comment: This code has several issues: How do you know the file is the platform default encoding? How do you know that encoding uses a single byte per character? Won't the FileReader need to be closed if reading throws an exception?

Comment: Here's [a better question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/326390/778118) that has been around for awhile.

Comment: There are more issues. How do you know the file size fits in an `int?` How do you know the file fits into memory? And finally, and the biggest issue of all, how do you know that `reader.read(chars)` filled the buffer?

Comment: You can also add 'how do you know that the line separator was \n?'

Comment: needed to insert this as the while statement to prevent null -->
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)

Comment: @ChristophHa Adding a line terminator *after* calling `readLine()` doesn't have anything to do with what happened inside `readLine()`.

Answer (score -5):

> How can we read data from a text file and store in a String Variable?

Err, read data from the file and store it in a String variable. It's just code. Not a real question so far.

> Is it possible to pass the filename in a method and it would return the String which is the text from the file.

Yes it's possible. It's also a very bad idea. You should deal with the file a part at a time, for example a line at a time. Reading the entire file into memory before you process any of it adds latency; wastes memory; and assumes that the entire file will fit into memory. One day it won't. You don't want to do it this way.

Comment: That would be great if u add some example, it would really help for beginner